# Pitch on a patio roof

Tags: roof, waterproofing

Recently I decided to re-roof my patio because it has been leaking in several places. That's when I noticed that my patio had very little rain run-off.

My patio is 24' wide by 17' deep. The roof starts at a height of 101 1/2" and runs to a low of 95".

Before I re-roof, I'd like to know if this is enough run-off.

We live in Sacramento, California and we generally get only a handful of heavy downpours per year.